# Linear equivalence vs algebraic equivalence of divisors on smooth projective surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, equivalence-relations, surfaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $D_1, D_2$ be two divisors on $X$. Is it true that $D_1$ is linearly equivalent to $D_2$ if and only if $D_1$ is algebraically equivalent to $D_2$?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: No. Hint: this isn't true for non-rational curves, e.g. elliptic curves; use that to come up with an example for surfaces.

Comment: @Dubh: I am sorry, I do not understand. I will make the question more precise.

Comment: I understood the question already. Do you know why the statement is false for curves? Once you do, it is not hard to turn this into an example for surfaces.

Comment: @Dubh: Could you please give a counterexample. I guess you mean any surface $X$ such that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is non-zero.

Comment: Could someone possibly give a proof for the true implication (linear implies algebraic)? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let me write out an example to show that the answer to the OP's question is "no".

First, if $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $\geq 1$, then all divisors of the same degree are algebraically equivalent. On the other hand, the linear equivalence classes of these divisors form a $g$-dimensional abelian variety, called the *Jacobian* variety of $X$. In particular, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct points on $C$, then they are not linearly equivalent as divisors on $C$.

Now consider the surface $X=C \times \mathbf P^1$. The pullback map $\pi^*: Pic(C) \rightarrow Pic(X)$ is injective, so the divisors $\pi^*(p)$ and $\pi^*(q)$ are still not linearly equivalent, although they are evidently algebraically equivalent.