# Linear equivalence implies algebraic equivalence for divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863041/linear-equivalence-vs-algebraic-equivalence-of-divisors-on-smooth-projective-sur): can someone provide a proof of the true implication (linear implies algebraic)? I am taking definitions from Griffiths-Harris, 461.

I'm afraid I really fail to see how the existence of a (meromorphic) section whose principal divisor is $D$ implies the "deformation" property at the base of the definition of algebraic equivalence.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write out the definitions. Suppose $C,D$ are divisors on $X$. They're linearly equivalent if there is a meromorphic function $f$ so that $C=D+(f)$, or in other words, the map $\mathcal{O}(C)\to \mathcal{O}(D)$ given by $1\mapsto f$ is an isomorphism. They are algebraically equivalent if there exists a connected scheme $T$ with points $t_1,t_2\in T$ and a line bundle $L$ on $X\times T$ so that $L|_{X\times t_1}\cong \mathcal{O}(C)$ and $L|_{X\times t_2}\cong\mathcal{O}(D)$.

Do you see a natural choice of $T$ for the case of two linearly equivalent divisors?

Comment: Perhaps $\mathbb A^1$  with as $L$ something related to the zero locus of some kind of combination of $f$ and $t$ (the variable associated to $\mathbb A^1$)?

Comment: Think harder. Does the one point space work?

Comment: Of course! I did not take the "isomorphism" into account. So with one point one just chooses $L=\mathcal O(D_1)$ and it works. Thanks! Just a thing about algebraic equivalence: how does one prove that the definition with bundles implies the one with divisors? (Cfr. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-727-topics-in-algebraic-geometry-algebraic-surfaces-spring-2008/lecture-notes/lect2.pdf for this latter.)

Comment: Guess. Take $L_1=\mathcal O(D_1),L_2=\mathcal O(D_2)$ as in the definition in the linked paper. Take $T=\mathbb P^1$, $t_1=0,t_2=\infty$. Then the divisor on $X\times T$ given by $f(x)=t$ satisfies $f(x)=0$ iff $x\in D_1$, $f(x)=\infty$ iff $x\in D_2$, for a suitable choice of representatives $D_1,D_2$.