# "Universal" line bundle over the Picard variety $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, picard-scheme

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}$This question is inspired by my attempt to answer [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839566/deformation-and-algebraic-equivalence-relation/4845904). At the end of my answer, there is a missing step, which I don't know how to fill.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$. By Hodge theory, the Picard variety
$$\Pic^0(X) = H^1(X, \mathcal O_X) / H^1(X, \mathbb Z)$$
is an abelian variety.

*Question*. Is there a line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X \times \Pic^0(X)$ such that $$\mathcal L|_{X \times \{L\}} \cong L\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
for each point $L \in \Pic^0(X)$?

If $X$ is an abelian variety, the Picard variety is the dual abelian variety, $\Pic^0(X) = X^\vee$, and a choice for $\mathcal L$ is the so called *Poincaré bundle*, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_variety#Polarisation_and_dual_abelian_variety) or [1,2].

According to the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Picard+scheme#definition), the relative Picard functor is representable, and hence there should be a unique tatological class $[\mathcal L] \in \Pic^0(X \times \Pic^0(X)) / q^*\Pic^0(\Pic^0X)$, where $q: X \times \Pic^0(X) \to \Pic^0(X)$ is the projection map. So any representative $\mathcal L \in \Pic^0(X \times \Pic^0(X))$ of $[\mathcal L]$ should satisfy \eqref{eq1}.

But is there an easier way to construct such a bundle, without showing that $\Pic^0(X)$ represents the relative Picard functor? (Is that even true? nLab doesn't explicitly claim this, and I'm simply going by association here.)

---

[1] Birkenhake, Lange, *Complex abelian varieties*

[2] Mumford, *Abelian varieties*

Comment: Hartshorne constructs in CH.IV the universal family for an elliptic curve. Have you read this proof?

Comment: @hm2020 Tbh, I haven't. But the case of elliptic curves is already covered by the case of abelian varieties, so Hartshorne's construction should lead to the Poincaré bundle.

Comment: On an elliptic curve $E$, HH gives an explicit definition of the Poincare bundle $P_E$ on $E\times E$ as follows: $P_E:=L(\Delta)\otimes p^*L(-p_0)$. Here $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Hence the definition does not involve "representable functors" and the "Yoneda Lemma". The proof that $P_E$ is the universal family does.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was a way to show something along those lines using the Albanese, which happens to be the dual abelian variety, but I don't quite remember the details right now.

Comment: Essentially, if you're happy with the existence of the Poincaré bundle for abelian varieties, then the Albanese should let you somehow transfer it to any projective variety through $\mathop{Pic}^0(X)\cong \mathop{Pic}^0(\mathop{Alb}(X))$?

Comment: @Ben This might work, I wasn't aware of the isomorphism. I guess it is pull-back along the Albanese map $X \to \operatorname{Alb}(X)$?

Comment: Or rather just $\operatorname{Pic}^0(\operatorname{Alb}(X)) = \operatorname{Alb}(X)^\vee = \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$.

Comment: @Ben If you write this into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @red_trumpet - in the case of an elliptic curve - it should be possible to verify directly that $P_E$ has the desired property.

Comment: @hm2020 Yes, indeed. If you restrict $P_E$ to $E \times \{p\}$ for $p \in E$, you get $P_E|_{E \times \{p\}} = \mathcal O(p - p_0)$, and every degree zero line bundle on $E$ is of that form.